# Aptana Studio 3 install using yum

Tags: installation, aptana3, yum

Is it possible to install aptana studio (the stand alone version) via yum so that it will appear in my menu?

Answer (score 8):

I just did it without Yum, so I'll write it up. 
Fedora 16 Aptana install without yum including icons

Download your version from http://aptana.org/products/studio3/download and extract Aptana 3 to a folder.

Open a root shell and move the extracted folder to /usr/local/bin or wherever you install things.

```
mv Aptana_Studio_3 /usr/local/bin/
```

Go there.

```
cd /usr/local/bin/Aptana_Studio_3
```

Add it to your system path if you want to be able to launch it from the shell:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add/edit the PATH line to include your aptana dir:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/Aptana_Studio_3
```

Save/exit and open a new shell. Test that you can launch it.

```
AptanaStudio3
```

Still in the folder you just created, make a symlink so it's easier to launch:

```
ln -s AptanaStudio3 aptana
```

Test the symlink

```
aptana
```

Add the icon in gnome 3, as root:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

Create a new file

```
nano aptana-studio-3.desktop
```

Add this to the file (edit path depending where you put it before):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Aptana Studio 3
Exec=/usr/local/bin/Aptana_Studio_3/aptana
Icon=/usr/local/bin/Aptana_Studio_3/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=Development
```

Save it.

Done.

Note- this will not put aptana in the PATH of everyone, just yourself. You could edit /etc/.bashrc or other global environment config file to make sure everyone has it.

In this example however, everyone will get it in their menus.

From there, open the Applications menu -> Programming and drag aptana to your dock, if you want.

This works in fc16 compiz desktop but should work for other recent redhat flavors.

Answer (score 2):

Two additional notes:

- `gedit ~/.bash_profile` could also be edited for individual path, it comes by default with every GNOME installation in case you don't have nano.
- in case you can't lunch `AptanaStudio3` after editing the path variable, you need to refresh the path variable by yourself. You can do this you can type `PATH=$PATH:/opt/Aptana_Studio_3`, being this path the path you used to install Aptana Studio 3